# Move MOSS 2007 Sharepoint Site to a New Server

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have a MOSS 2007 site hosted on a server.  I would like to move it to a new server, databases and all.  When looking for help, people generally say, "Just a run a backup, install MOSS on the new server and perform a restore."  Is that good enough?  I can't seem to get it to work.  What kind of options do I need to select when installing the new MOSS 2007?  Do I need to attach the old databases?  It's a single server, not a farm, with four site collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good write up here:

http://www.sharepointblogs.com/adnan/archive/2007/01/26/move-moss-2007-web-application-to-another-server.aspx

Make sure the source server and the destination server are the same version (including service packs and patches).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide Rob posted. Do NOT use the built in backup feature in SharePoint to move the site. It may seem to work at first, but sooner or later you will end up with problems due to references to the old server.